# How to display a single property from a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display a single property from a list of objects in the front end like so. DocumentRepoVaccineTypes is the list of objects in the View model. The information that is displayed in the front end is this in the column "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[EHS.Entities.DocumentRepositoryVaccineTypes]"

```
public virtual ICollection<DocumentRepositoryVaccineTypes> DocumentRepoVaccineTypes { get; set; }
```

---

```
 <td>
   @document.DocumentRepoVaccineTypes
 </td>
```

Comment: Well, you're going to need a row for each one, so just `foreach` over the hashset and spit out a new HTML row for each one

Comment: @itsme86 thats the thing, It all should be shown in the same row  just separated by commas. its not even a big list, just 1-5 things to be displayed in the row comma separated though I am unaware of how to pull this off.

Comment: You could have been a little clearer about that. In that case you should have `@string.Join(", ", document.DocumentRepoVaccineTypes);` That will show whatever your `.ToString()` override displays. If that's not what you want, again, clearly state which property you want to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@String.Join(", ", document.DocumentRepoVaccineTypes.Select(type => type.SomeProperty))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! <3